# How to determine in which order IHostedServices are being called at shutdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, application-shutdown, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm maintaining a integration package that allows my users to integrate my library with ASP.NET Core. This package must be compatible with all versions of ASP.NET Core starting at 2.1. At application shutdown my integration package must be able to execute asynchronous cleanup, and unfortunately can't take a dependency on `IAsyncDisposable` through `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` (see below).

The only way this, therefore, seems feasible is by registering an `IHostedService` implementation. It's `StopAsync` method is called at shutdown:

```
public sealed class ShutdownHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public MyLibaryCleanupObject Obj;
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token) => Task.CompletedTask;
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token) => this.Obj.CleanupAsync();
}

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(new ShutdownHostedService { Obj = ... });
```

Application developers, however, can of course add their own `IHostedService` implementations, which might interact with my library. This is why it is important for my own `IHostedService` implementation to be called last. But here lies the problem.

With the introduction of ASP.NET Core 2.1 application developers can choose between using the new `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host` and the (now deprecated) `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost`. With `WebHost`, at shutdown, `IHostedService` implementations are called in order of registration, whereas with `Host`, `IHostedService` implementations are called in ***opposite order*** of registration.

This is problematic for me, because my hosted service should be called last. As application developers might use my integration package in their existing ASP.NET Core application, they might still use `WebHost`, which is why it is important to support that scenario.

**Question: What would be a reliable way to determine in what 'mode' the ASP.NET Core application runs, so I can decide to add my hosted service first or last?**

Alternatively, to prevent falling into the XY-problem trap, I'm open to completely different solutions that solve my problem of implementing "asynchronous shutdown".

Note on `IAsyncDisposable`:

One solution that would come to mind (as Ian rightfully notes in the comments) is to add an `IAsyncDisposable` Singleton registration to the `ServiceCollection`. This would allow asynchronous cleanup at shutdown. Unfortunately, due to constraints (explained [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/867)) it's impossible for my integration package to take a dependency on `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` and, therefore, not on `IAsyncDisposable`. This is an unfortunate situation that certainly complicates the matter. As a matter of fact, the reason for not being able to take a dependency on `IAsyncDisposable` is the reason I'm looking for alternative ways of implementing asynchronous shutdown code.

Comment: I strongly doubt that background services are intended to be used this way, and I'm certain that the order they're stopped in is an implementation detail, therefore completely unguaranteed and subject to change at any time, so I would definitely suggest looking into other ways to accomplish this. My suggestion would be `IAsyncDisposable`, which is supported natively on Core 3.0 and up, and has a shim for older versions via the `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` NuGet package. Alternatively, ask directly on the ASP.NET Core GitHub repo.

Comment: Hi @IanKemp, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately using `IAsyncDisposable` is out of the picture (I should have stated this more clearly in my question). `IAsyncDisposable` is exactly the problem why I'm in this situation. The new version of the library I'm developing, [purposely](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/867) removes the dependency on `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` which disallows me from adding an `IAsyncDisposable` registration to the `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: As a worst case if no automated solution is found, create a configuration option (flag) that can be used to indicate the desired order. (just off the top of my head)

Comment: Seems to me that your best option would be to stop development of pre-.NET Standard 2.1 versions of SimpleInjector. It's admirable to want to continue to support people using older versions of .NET, but having to remove code to do that and use what is essentially a very hacky maybe-workaround with `IHostedService` suggests to me that it's really not worth your time.

Comment: Another option could be to register a handler to `IApplicationLifetime` either `ApplicationStopping` or `ApplicaionStopped`

Comment: Agreed with Nkosi, utilizing the application lifetime seems like a better bet for this kind of task, especially considering that you only want a _cleanup_ step but not an actual startup. The problem is that the lifetime events do not support asynchronous work. What might work would be to provide a custom `IHostLifetime` but that makes things also a bit more complicated since you need to support the different lifetimes…

Comment: @Nkosi, That interface os problematic in itself because it is deprecated and might even be already removed from ASP.NET 5.0.

Comment: The solution I ended up using is 'simply' to call `CleanupAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` from a `Dispose` method. See my own answer.

Comment: The correct interface for 3.0 and later is `IHostApplicationLifetime` btw.

Comment: @poke, that's correct. That interface, however, is not available under 2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I end up using is identical to the solution chosen by Microsoft's `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host` class and doesn't involve using `IHostedService` instances. The `Host` class contains the following `Dispose` method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This might raise some eyebrows and might be seen as a bad practice, but don't forget that:

- This code is guaranteed to run in the context of ASP.NET Core, where this code can't cause a deadlock
- This code runs just once at shutdown, so performance isn't an issue here.

This is why Microsoft's `Host` class can take this approach, and it means that it is a safe approach for my library to do as well.